# Compiler can not find AndroidInstrumentationTestCase2 when building Android app test code with Android makefile build system

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-build

I have a project with some Android test code in it (with the appropriate elements, `<uses-library>` and `<instrumentation>`, added to `AndroidManifest.xml`).  This works fine in Eclipse.  However, it fails to build with `mm`, claiming that it can't find the test-runner classes:

```
/home/orospakr/code/my-android/packages/apps/MyApp/src/ca/orospakr/myapp/test/functional/MyActivityTest.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
location: package android.test
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
                   ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this problem for about a day before finding the fix.  If you are using an **Android.mk** file to build your application, make sure to add this line:

```
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
```

Other solutions I found suggested adding this line to the application section of the manifest, but it doesn't seem to make any difference for me:

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```